# How to create a gunzip file of a partition for backup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel

I have a linux virtual machine with 2 hard disks /dev/xvda and /dev/xvdb where all my data is on /dev/svda and /dev/xvdb is specially for backup purposes.

I am trying to take back up using `dd if=/dev/xvda of=/dev/xvdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync` command. But I dont think that's a good way of getting a compressed backup. How can I use the dd command to take the backup in .gz file format on /dev/xvdb so that I can copy it anywhere I want?

Answer (score 1):

`dd` is not the right tool for the job.
Try using `cat /dev/xvda | gzip >/mnt/backup-some-date.raw.gz`.

You can use `xz` for better compression.

`/mnt` or `/mnt/backups`, are traditional places to mount disks. Mount there the disk where you want to store your backups.

To restore:

```
zcat /mnt/backup-some-date.raw.gz >/dev/xvda
```

Something very important to keep in mind is that you *must* unmount or at least make read only, the partition to read or write. That makes it a poor method to backup live systems and completely impossible to restore a live system.

Comment: how will I restore this backup? and what is /mnt I would like to store the backup in another partition /dev/xvdb

Comment: Improved the response.